# Touch узнать когда палец сменил направление

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как узнать если палец двигался и сменил направление то есть двигался в перед а потом начал назад

Answer (score 3, accepted):

deltaPosition - вернет вектор который указывает куда направляеться палец, если он всегда (допустим) по x и y в плюсе и внезапно ушел в минус то это значит что палец изменил направления

Comment: В зависимости от устройства значение параметра `deltaPosition` может быть не стабильным при движении. Поэтому по хорошему нужна фильтрация входящих данных и рассчитывать направление движения в коде